# Ubuntu 14.10 freezing

Tags: 14.10, radeon, freeze

Ubuntu 14.10 with the following hardware:
Wireless:  Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
Graphics: ATI Radeon 280 (fglrx driver)
CPU: 4690K 
Motherboard: ASRock Z97 Pro4
Memory: 16G
Hardrive: SSD (AHCI set in BIOS)

This computer was running windows 7 for a long time without any issues, so there shouldn't be any hardware problems (I did run multiple hardware checks including Memtest).

After hours or at random time (when playing game for instance) the computer will freeze.  This is a hard freeze.  For instance sometimes I can't even do "Magic" SysRq trick (this might be due to frozen keyboard).

Now here is the weird part.  There is NOTHING in syslog at all nor in dmesg.  The log simply stops.  For instance yesterday it died at 5am next log was at 11:30 am when I rebooted.

Does anybody have any suggests as to where to look further?  I am suspecting that this is probably a graphic adapter issue.  Primarily since nothing else is particularly unusual about my setup.

Thank you!

Comment: try to run `gnome-system-monitor` in the background to watch your resources. Try to log using `top` like `top>mylog.log` in a bash script.

Comment: I have monitored the resources, as well as taking continual /var/log/syslog polls (so that I can have it after reboot).  The load on the box is at essentially 0 .

Comment: have you tried to access your machine during a freeze via `ssh` ? if it is just your graphics card it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Well so I found the issue; although still don't know if it is hardware or software.

The issue was in fact with the Video Card.  I swapped the card with another computer and for 2 days now I've had 0 issues.

What concerns me is that this card is working fine in Windows 7, and that the freeze was so hard.  Everything was shutdown, including networking.  Heck I couldn't do magic sysrq!!!!!

So I have no idea how a module, any module, could cause such a crash within an OS.